# Having a problem matching a html element using Preg_Match

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to match a html element but I don't think its matching since $titles is empty - can anyone correct me?

My preg_match:

```
   preg_match_all("~<td align=\"left\" width=\"50%\">[^<]*. <b><a href=\"(.*?)\">[^<]*</a>~i", $main, $titles);
```

Example HTML to match:

```
//<td align="left" width="50%">1. <b><a title="Wat" href="http://www.exmple.com/q.html">Wat</a></b><br></td>
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks all for any help

Comment: I dont know how many times the community has to tell people... dont parse html with a regex.. use SimpleXml, DOMDocument, Zend_Dom_Query, SimpleHtml, etc.. :-)

Comment: I am aware of this, but this is an old script that needs to be fixed, no time to rewrite it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to match `title="Wat"` in the `<a>` tag.

I'd suggest not using a regex to parse it though. I'm not too familiar with PHP but I'm sure it already has something that will do most of the work for you.

Comment: If the document you're searching is valid XHTML you can use the built in simpleXML parser, but many times it is not.

Comment: @Corey - aaah! Thanks, I did not even notice that. Dear God! Putting `title=\"[^<]*\"` - seems to get it work.

Answer (score 1):

As i said in my comment regex is rarely if ever the proper tool to use when trying to parse html. Im foing to use an example of Zend_Dom_Query, one of th ecomponetns in Zend Framework simply because i havent seen it recommended on one of these questions yet. So...

```
$dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($htmlHaystack);
$anchors = $dom->query('//td/a[@title]'); // xpath here
if(count($anchors) > 0)
{
  $titles = array();
  foreach($anchors as $element)
  {
     $titles[] = $element->getAttribute('title');
  }
}
else
{
  $title = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string='<td align="left" width="50%">1. <b><a title="Wat" href="http://www.exmple.com/q.html">Wat</a></b><br></td>';
$s = explode("</a>",$string);
foreach($s as $k){
   if (strpos($k,"href")!==FALSE){
        echo preg_replace('/.*href="|">.*/ms',"",$k);
   }
}
```